# Preloading gif until image fully loads does not appear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fullscreen image and a button, which when clicked, triggers the appearance of a second image above (and others actually; I simplified here to one image for the sake of this question).

**What I want to implement**: I would like that when the user clicks on the button, while the image is loading (= until the image is fully loaded and available, the user), the user should see a red fullscreen image and a loading gif as below.
That is to say, **AS SOON AS** he clicked the button, he should see a red fullscreen image and a loading gif as below (note that i don't care if the green button is visible or not during the loading):

[image]

I am using [this method](https://www.perpetual-beta.org/weblog/silky-smooth-image-loading.html) to only load the image when it is fully loaded (to avoid the usual cases on bad connections where the image appear gradually starting on top then extend to the bottom).

I tried many things but nothing works: i don't manage to load this red screen and a loading gif just after touching the green button (see jsfiddle Demo).

To really make sure it's working, I use chrome Dev tools and throttle the Connection Speed in the 'Network' Tab, this way I have time to see if the red background and the loading gif appear timely.

Here is my code:

```js
lazy_load_background_assets();

function lazy_load_background_assets() {
  $("#main-image-zone").css({
    'backgroundImage': 'url(' + $("#background-img").attr('data-src') + ')',
    //smooth transition for webkit browsers
    'transition': 'background-image 0.2s ease',
    '-webkit-transition': 'background-image 0.2s ease'
  });

  $('#st15').on('click', function(e) {
    var $nextImage = $('#contentAfterInitialImage').find('#backgroundAsset-15');
    console.log($nextImage);

    // prevents the loaded image if it is already loaded
    var src = $nextImage.data('lazyclick-src');
    console.log(src);
    if (typeof src !== "undefined" && src != "") {
      $nextImage.attr('src', src);
      $nextImage.attr('data-lazyclick-src', '');
    }
  });

}
```

```css
.page-bckdCover {
  min-height: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: scroll;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.page-bckdImgCover {
  display: none;
}

section {
  display: block;
}

img {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

//Progressive Loading
//inspired by https://www.perpetual-beta.org/weblog/silky-smooth-image-loading.html
.image-loader {
  background: inherit;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden !important;
  img {
    position: absolute;
  }
}

.image-loading {
  opacity: 0;
}

.image-loaded {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 0.2s ease;
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

// fix users seeing alts on image load
img.page-bckdImgCover {
  color: transparent;
}

img.page-bckdCover {
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--Progressive Loading
    inspired by https://www.perpetual-beta.org/weblog/silky-smooth-image-loading.html -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  // swap 'image-loading' class for 'image-loaded'
  function imageLoaded(img) {
    img.classList.add('image-loaded');
    img.classList.remove('image-loading');
  };
  //]]>
</script>


<section id="main-image-zone" class="page-bckdCover" style=" background: url('data:image/jpeg;base64,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');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-size:cover;
              background-position:50% 50%;">
  <img data-src="http://prestige-paradise.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/photo-hotel.jpg" class="page-bckdImgCover" id="background-img">


  <div id="contentAfterInitialImage" class="image-loader">
    <img data-lazyclick-src="https://www.gentlegiant.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/New-York.jpg" class="page-bckdCover" style="width:100%; background: url('https://m.popkey.co/163fce/Llgbv_s-200x150.gif') center no-repeat; 
            background-color: red;" data-id="trucgenial15" id="backgroundAsset-15" alt="new york" onload="imageLoaded(this)">
  </div>


</section>


<div id="buttons" style="position: fixed;top: 0;left: 0;width: 100%;height: 100%;z-index: 10;">
  <!-- Throbbers' Modal - Gather here the various types of throbbers -->

  <div style="width:200px; height: 30px;background-color: green; top: 80%;left: 20%;position: absolute;" id="st15">
    <span>
            <a title="yoyoy" href="www.yahoo.com"></a>
          </span>
  </div>

</div>

<!--Progressive Loading
    inspired by https://www.perpetual-beta.org/weblog/silky-smooth-image-loading.html -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  // get all 'image-loader' containers
  function imageLoader() {
    var containers = document.getElementsByClassName('image-loader');
    var containerList = Array.prototype.slice.call(containers);
    containerList.forEach(getImage);
  }
  // get all images from within 'image-loader' containers
  function getImage(element) {
    var images = element.getElementsByTagName('img');
    var imageList = Array.prototype.slice.call(images);
    imageList.forEach(addImageLoadingClass);
  }
  // add 'image-loading' class
  function addImageLoadingClass(element) {
    element.classList.add('image-loading');
  }
  // launch the image loader
  (function() {
    imageLoader();
  })();
  //]]>
</script>
```

I tried in the html to no success:

```
<div  id="contentAfterInitialImage"
            class="image-loader"
            style="background: url('https://m.popkey.co/163fce/Llgbv_s-200x150.gif') center no-repeat; 
        background-color: red;">
```

But the result is you see the Red background and the loading gif from the page load , not only after the user clicks the button...

I created a jsFiddle so that it's easier to see the problem and iterate the solution.

- JsFiddle Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5c90soLs/
- Jsfiddle fullscreen Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/5c90soLs/embedded/result/https://jsfiddle.net/q4nk0gwj/embedded/result/  => very useful to analyze the issue and simulate on Chrome/firefox/.. Dev Tools a slow connection
- JsFiddle Demo where I try to add the red background and the loading gif but with no success: https://jsfiddle.net/4nsnctsy/